# Googlechart javascript chart.getSelection fails with ampersand

Tags: javascript

I have a selectHandler on my googlechart - which works great until there is an AMPERSAND in the value being extracted. If I replace the ampersand with %26 it works, but the &26 is displayed, not the ampersand.

John would work - the qry ran against the DB returns expected values.
Janet&John would not work - only Janet would be used as the qry value against the DB...

relevant part of the code:

```
       function selectHandler() {
      var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
      if (selectedItem) {
        var param_val = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
        run_find(param_val)
      }
    }
       function run_find(param_val) {
       theParam = '[Context Here]|' + param_val;
        theURL = "DBQry&param=" + theParam;
        window.location = theURL;
      }
```

It is the "selectedItem" that splits up the value at the ampersand.

Anyone know how I can use encodeURIComponent on the selectedItem variable IF that is the correct thing to do? Or what should I do to stop the string being split at the ampersand?

Kindest

Glorifindal

Answer (score 0):

OK, worked it out -

for those who are as lost in Javascript as myself:

```
            var param_valEnc = encodeURIComponent( param_val ) ;
        run_find(param_valEnc)
```

I realise that I exist in the minority there...